# Ayuda, activity se cierra al lanzarse

Tags: java, android

soy nuevo y estoy empezando con Android en Android Studio.. Tengo una aplicación sencilla que tiene dos activitys, la 1° pide y envia un nombre y la segunda lo muestra, pero al lanzarse la segunda no llega a mostrar el nombre, se cierra la aplicacion sin mostrar el nombre..

Main Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtNombre;
private Button btnAceptar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
    txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    btnAceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);

    //Implementamos el evento click del botón
    btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creamos el Intent
            Intent intent =
                    new Intent(MainActivity.this, SaludoActivity.class);

            //Creamos la información a pasar entre actividades
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString());

            //Añadimos la información al intent
            intent.putExtras(b);

            //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
            startActivity(intent);


     }
        });
    }
}
```

Actity saludo (2° activity)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SaludoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txtSaludo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);

    //Localizar los controles
    txtSaludo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSaludo);

    //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
    txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + bundle.getString("NOMBRE"));
}
}
```

Que puedo hacer para que no se cierre la app al presionar el boton aceptar?.. Para probar la app estoy usando bluestack no se si tendra algo que ver.. Gracias!

Comment: si vas a desarrollar en Android asegura siempre revisar el mensaje de error dentro del LogCat con esto fácilmente podrías encontrar el error. Agrega a tu pregunta el mensaje de error en el LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

Debes siempre agregar el Logcat para definir el problema, ya que pueden ser varias causas para que se cierre tu aplicación.

Noto que tu código es correcto, lo primero es asegurar tu Activity SaludoActivity, este registrada en tu AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="SaludoActivity" />
```

Aunque el código es correcto al leer el bundle en la segunda actividad otro detalle que podría cerrar tu aplicación es que el valor de "NOMBRE"  podría ser nulo, te recomiendo agregar esta validación:

```
 //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle.getString("NOMBRE") != null){
    //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
    txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + bundle.getString("NOMBRE"));
}
```

Comment: Gracias!, SaludoActivity no estaba registrada en el manifest..

Comment: que bien Enzo, creo que es algo muy común cuando inicias desarrollando en android, esto y el permiso de internet..  =P

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas usando Bundle y este es para fragmentos, con el intent es suficiente: usa esto

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SaludoActivity.class);
//Creamos la información a pasar entre actividades
intent.putExtra("NOMBRE", txtNombre.getText().toString());
//Iniciamos la nueva actividad
startActivity(intent);
```

Actity saludo (2° activity)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);
    final int nombre = getIntent().getIntExtra("NOMBRE", 0);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nombreExtra = "";
      // Validar que este llegando 
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("NOMBRE")) {
       //  get del parametro 
            nombreExtra = intent.getStringExtra("NOMBRE");
        }

    //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
    txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + nombreExtra);
}
}
```

PS: podemos mejorar tu codigo en base a esto :
1. como NOMBRE es una costante crea una contacte statica e immutable para esto, 
2. tambien para respetar el principio de Single resposability deja el el put Extra dentro de activity 
private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "NOMBRE";

Entonces tus dos Activity quedarina de esta forma:

```
public class SaludoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "NOMBRE";
private TextView txtSaludo;

public static Intent getStartSaludoActivityIntent(@NonNull Activity activity, String nombre) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SaludoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, nombre);
        return intent;
    }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);
    //Localizar los controles
    txtSaludo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSaludo);

final int nombre = getIntent().getIntExtra("NOMBRE", 0);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String nombreExtra = "";
          // Validar que este llegando 
            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_NAME)) {
           //  get del parametro 
                nombreExtra = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
            }

        //Construimos el mensaje a mostrar
        txtSaludo.setText("Hola " + nombreExtra);   
}
}
```

y desde tu Main activity llamas el metodo statico

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText txtNombre;
private Button btnAceptar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Obtenemos una referencia a los controles de la interfaz
    txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    btnAceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAceptar);

    //Implementamos el evento click del botón
    btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
        startActivity(SaludoActivity.getStartSaludoActivityIntent(MainActivity.this, txtNombre.getText().toString()));


     }
        });
    }
}
```